# Android USBDevice: how to determine "vendor name" and "device name" from vendorID and DeviceID?

Tags: android, usb, android-launcher

I have a USB device and I want to know how I can identify "vendor name" and "device name"  from vendorID and DeviceID.

And the Device name I get from USBManagers' DeviceList Hashmap does not look valid.

Finally what I want is something like this:

(Silicon - Power 8GB)

Answer (score 5):

You can get `VendorId` and `ProductId` from:

```
UsbDevice.getVendorId();
UsbDevice.getProductId();
```

You need to convert the int values to hexadecimal and compare them against a list of vendor ids/ product ids.

You can find this list [here](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids).

I'll leave the parsing to you, but it's pretty straightforward. You can find the structure at the top of the file:

> # Syntax:
>   # vendor   vendor_name
>   #        device   device_name   <-- single tab
>   #                interface   interface_name   <-- two tabs

Comment: Thanks. about the list you mentioned: Isn't there any built-in such list in android source code?

Answer (score 2):

In API 21 these methods were added. It's as simple as here:

```
    UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(USB_SERVICE);
        if (usbManager != null) {
            HashMap<String, UsbDevice> devices = usbManager.getDeviceList();
            for (String key: devices.keySet()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Device Name: " + devices.get(key).getDeviceName());
                Log.d(TAG, "Manufacturer Name: " + devices.get(key).getManufacturerName());
                Log.d(TAG, "Product Name: " + devices.get(key).getProductName());
            }
        }
```

You could filter by vendorId and print it too.